# How to check if a pair exists in SQL table. Constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `PILOT1` and `PILOT2` SIN pair with `SHIP ID`.
I do not want this:

```
ship1   111 222 4   20  idk 23.33   gop

ship1   222 111 4   20  idk 23.33   gop
```

See how the `shipID` is the same and the same pilots are operating the ship. I want a way to constraint this. This is valid since the pilot IDs are different:

```
ship1   111 222 4   20  idk 23.33   gop

ship1   232 111 4   20  idk 23.33   gop
```

```
CREATE TABLE Ship (
    shipID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    pilot1_SIN varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    pilot2_SIN varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    years_in_operation INT,
    num_of_seats INT,
    manufacturer varchar(30),
    advertising_revenue FLOAT,
    fuel_type varchar(15)
    PRIMARY KEY (shipID, pilot1_SIN, pilot2_SIN),
    FOREIGN KEY (pilot1_SIN) REFERENCES Pilot(SINumber),
    FOREIGN KEY (pilot2_SIN) REFERENCES Pilot(SINumber),
    CONSTRAINT check_pilots CHECK (pilot1_SIN != pilot2_SIN)
);
```

Comment: Use a trigger on the "before insert" event to check for the condition.

Comment: Could you change the check to `CHECK(pilot1_SIN < pilot2_SIN)`?

Comment: MySQL ignores `CHECK` constraints.

Comment: How do I do CHECK with MySQL version 5.7.23 @Barmar

Comment: @Yushey As suggested in another comment, use a trigger to test if the constraint would be violated.

Comment: One way is just to insert both.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as pointed out by @Barmar, even in version 8.0, MySQL just flat out ignores any `CHECK CONSTRAINTS`

You could use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger as suggested @TheImpaler

For an outside the box solution, you could use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

```
pilot_check_unique VARCHAR(23) AS (CONCAT(
  LEAST(pilot1_SIN,pilot2_SIN), ':', GREATEST(pilot1,pilot2) 
)) NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

If the table is not InnoDB, you will have to make the column `STORED` by placing `STORED` before `UNIQUE`, this will of course increase the disk space used by the table

Sadly, this will not validate that `pilot1` does not equal `pilot2`, I guess you could add

```
pilot_check_not_equal TINYINT(1) AS (
  CASE WHEN pilot1_SIN != pilot2_SIN THEN 1 END CASE
) NOT NULL
```

but I'm not 100% sure it will be allowed

**N.B.** Having said all this, I find that in my projects there are always validation issues that cannot be solved easily at the database layer. I'd be tempted to validate this case in the application layer. As long as you only have one area of code that `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s this code, you should be fine.

**ADDENDUM**

Another option is to separate your `Ship` table into `Ship` and `Ship_pilot`

```
CREATE TABLE Ship (
    shipID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    years_in_operation INT,
    num_of_seats INT,
    manufacturer varchar(30),
    advertising_revenue FLOAT,
    fuel_type varchar(15)
    PRIMARY KEY (shipID)
);

CREATE TABLE Ship_Pilot (
    shipID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    pilot_SIN varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    position TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (shipID, pilot_SIN),
    FOREIGN KEY (pilot_SIN) REFERENCES Pilot(SINumber),
    UNIQUE KEY (shipID, position)
);
```

This will you don't duplicate pilots or positions for a ship, but will allow you 0-256 different pilots per ship

**ASIDE**

I would also suggest the following

- Use `UNSIGNED` integer types for IDs
- Use `UNSIGNED` integers for `num_of_seats` and `years_in_operation`, presumably these cannot be negative
- Use a separate tables for each of `fuel_type` and `manufacturer` and reference them with an `UNSIGNED` integer, rather than duplicating names
- Your ship table has a composite PK, this will allow the same `shipID` multiple times in the same table (with different pilots) - is this correct?
- Use a `DECIMAL` or integer type for `advertising_revenue` for precision

Comment: Does it have to be stored?

Comment: Yep, otherwise it can't be indexed.. oh, maybe not!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
CREATE TABLE Ship (
shipID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
pilot1_SIN varchar(11) NOT NULL,
pilot2_SIN varchar(11) NOT NULL,
years_in_operation INT,
num_of_seats INT,
manufacturer varchar(30),
advertising_revenue FLOAT,
fuel_type varchar(15)
PRIMARY KEY (shipID, pilot1_SIN, pilot2_SIN),
FOREIGN KEY (pilot1_SIN) REFERENCES Pilot(SINumber),
FOREIGN KEY (pilot2_SIN) REFERENCES Pilot(SINumber),
);

create unique index IX_Unique on (Ship (least(pilot1_SIN, pilot2_SIN), greatest(pilot1_SIN, pilot2_SIN)));
```

Comment: Don't think that's right, presumably the same pilots can handle a different ship.. also it doesn't solve the problem posed in the question

Comment: Hmm. Primary key on three fields is already there. Why need a constraint on three fields?

Comment: They are trying to avoid Ship1 Pilot1 Pilot2 coexisting with Ship1 Pilot2 Pilot1

Comment: it's not working. are u missing a bracket or something?

Comment: It looks keys on expressions are only allowed from MySQL 8.0.13

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (id1 INT NOT NULL,id2 INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(id1,id2));

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT LEAST(4,9),GREATEST(4,9);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-----+-----+
| id1 | id2 |
+-----+-----+
|   4 |   9 |
+-----+-----+

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT LEAST(4,9),GREATEST(4,9);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '4-9' for key 'PRIMARY'
```